# parsing in Logstash whole files as one event each

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I want to monitor with Logstash a directory with individual files, that each describe an event and consist each of key-value pairs

```
   > /var/log/dir/history.*
   > head /var/log/dir/history.1234
     key1 = value1
     key2 = value2
     ...
```

The kv filter plugin can parse the key-value pairs, however the input needs to be some kind of multiline as to conflate each file into one event.

The multiline input plugin requires a pattern to match as well the what-keyword, if the event starts/ends at the pattern match.

Since I consider the whole file as one event, I have no real regex or so to match.

How can I parse one file as input as one event with logstash's multiline or is there a better input plugin for this use case?

Comment: If each file is written quickly, maybe you can use the `auto_flush_interval` parameter of the multiline filter?

Answer (score 0):

taking the solution from https://discuss.elastic.co/t/log-file-parsing-and-ingesting-into-es/247806/6

i.e., to ingest a whole file, the trick is to match on a not existing pattern

```
codec => multiline {
  pattern => "^Spalanzanidonotmatchinanycase"
  negate => true
  what => "previous"
  auto_flush_interval => 2
}
```